# Water effect with reverb

Tags: reverb

I'm looking to recreate or if there is a sample of this effect, under what name would it be?

It's at sec. 0:56 in this clip

Also here in sec. 0:26:

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like basic resonance on white noise to me. I made this using Ableton operator with white noise using a decay of 4.92 seconds and a release of 7.16 seconds, put through a 24dB band filter with a resonance of 5.42. Then a touch of reverb: https://soundcloud.com/lukofinc/la-femme-stack/s-I1yMU
It's not exactly the same but you get the idea.
You can download and use it if you want or have a go at making it yourself. Hope this has helped!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a sonar sound effect mixed with some subtle reverb to me.

Try messing around with some of the sonar sound effects over on [Freesound](https://www.freesound.org/search/?q=Sonar).

Answer (score 0):

The sound is repeated throughout both songs. The band uses a lot of vintage synthesizers; they seem to love keyboards. So I would take an educated guess.

Listening to the other sounds they use in their songs, I would say it's a synthesizer playing a single note. It is filtered(BP?) with high resonance. Then there is a heavy reverb applied. Both these things together makes it sound(as jdagenet said) like a sonar blip.

To recreate this sound without the right synth and reverb unit could be a challenge, so I would suggest using a sonar blip sample.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like the sonar effect is the closest I can get. I don't know if they actually use a synth to produce that sound because if that was the case they would be able to play it live, which they don't. It's only on the recorded versions.

I was looking for sonar samples but it's hard to find one with the right note.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a high pitched percussive sound going through an echo/reverb machine with high internal feedback setting.

The Space Echo is a pretty popular choice in the psych and analog electronic genres:

(check out from around 3:14)